# Crud module : Listing a OneToMany with a specific order

Tags: playframework, sql-order-by

I'm using Crud module and I can make it work well.

But when I displaying the form to add a new User (or edit an existing User), I have a list of Cities that are displayed in a non alphabetically way. I'd like to sort them based on the name.

I tried to add a @OrderBy to my model, but this doesn't work.

How can I do it?

Thanks for your help!

Here is my model for information :

```
@Entity
public class City extends Model {
    @Required
    @OrderBy  //doesn't work
    public String nomination; // I had to set this var to this name ...

    public String zipcode;

    public City(String nomination, String zipcode) {
        this.nomination = nomination;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.nomination;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code of the entities and the @OrderBy you added? To see the error. OrderBy should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT ON UPDATE**

I'm afraid it's nto trivial. In the framework the code that retrieves the list of cities is [this](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.java#L773) one. As you can see it doesn't add any "order by" to the query as it's generic. The CRUD tag that paints the rels ([here](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/modules/crud/app/views/tags/crud/relationField.html)) just iterates over that field.

The simplest solution would be to use the CRUD customization capabilites ([here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/crud)) and use teh #{crud.custom} tag to paint your own dropdown with the ordered list of cities.

**OLD ANSWER**

I believe your error is on where the @OrderBy annotation is placed. You should put it on the relation:

```
  @Entity 
    public class Foo{
       ...
       @OneToMany
       @OrderBy("nomination ASC")
       public List<City> cities;
       ...
    }
```

This way the list "cities" will be ordered by the parameter.

I just noticed that you mention you are using the CRUD module. In this case, as far as I remember, CRUD lists the fields ordered by the first column it displays. Try to change that column as per [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/crud) page so the name is the first column.

Comment: My model (User), have a relation to City, but with a @ManyToOne (public City city;, not List<City>). So this doesn't work :/ I tried to put the "nomination" in first, but no success here too :/

Comment: @cx42net I'm afraid I don't get it. Your User links to only 1 City, so where's the ordering problem in there? There is only one city. Could you describe in more detail in the question your User model and how are you traversing the rels to get the list of cities?

Comment: Here it goes, I updated my profil. I wasn't clear enough at first, maybe more now. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally did a crud.custom. That's sad we can't choose to order by ....

Comment: @cx42net CRUD module is a relatively simple implementation. It's powerful in a sense, but in many cases you are better off implementing your own. Hopefully Play 2.0 will improve this ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by hacking JPAPlugin.java:

```
--- a/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.java
+++ b/framework/src/play/db/jpa/JPAPlugin.java
@@ -771,7 +771,11 @@ public class JPAPlugin extends PlayPlugin {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Object> list() {
        - return getJPAContext().em().createQuery("from " + field.getType().getName()).getResultList();
        + String query = "from " + field.getType().getName();
        + if (field.isAnnotationPresent(OrderBy.class)) {
            + query += (" order by " + field.getAnnotation(OrderBy.class).value());
        + }
        + return getJPAContext().em().createQuery(query).getResultList();
        }
    };
}
```

This way you can annotate the City attribute on your User model with @OrderBy("name"), and you will have an ordered drop-down when editing your User object using the CRUD module:

```
@Entity 
public class User{
   ...
   @OneToMany
   @OrderBy("name ASC")
   public City city;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue today.

If you don't want to hack JPAPlugin or create custom fields every time you have a OneToMany relationship, you can also reorder them client-side via a little bit of JavaScript.

Here is use jQuery but you could also easily do it in Vanilla

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    innerSort = function (a, b) {
        return (a.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > b.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) ? 1 : -1;
    };
    $('select').each(function( index ) {
        var previousVal = $(this).val();
        $(this).find('option').sort(innerSort).appendTo($(this));
        $(this).val(previousVal);
    });
</script>
```

Just place this bit of code into the CRUD/layout.html template (you can override it to make your own, see Play tutorial), at the end of the page